# How to refactor this copy lines without empty ones from a RichTextBox to an ArrayList

Tags: c#, loops, arraylist, refactoring, richtextbox

I want the user to add proxy addresses with copy and paste from the program interface, and when the button is pressed, I want to copy them into arraylist and continue with arraylist, but when the number of lines is high, it takes quite a long time. When I added 10,000 proxies and tried the button, it gave an error after waiting for a while. How can I quickly add items in the richtextbox to the arraylist list?

My code:

```
ArrayList plist = new ArrayList();
    
if (richTextBox1.Lines.Length > 0 && checkBox1.Checked == true)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (richTextBox1.Lines[i].ToString() != "")
                        {
                            plist.Add(richTextBox1.Lines[i].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Probably not your main issue, but do note that `ArrayList` is deprecated and should be replaced by `List<T>`.

Comment: `When I added 10,000 proxies and tried the button, it gave an error after waiting for a while` what is that error? You're asking about a few things here, it doesn't matter how fast you add items to a collection if you can't figure out what's causing the error.

Comment: Side note, you *could add all items at one time* instead of individually. I say this because an `ArrayList` and `List<T>` will double in size when `Add` is called (in some cases). Instead of possibly increasing the size everytime by using `Add` like that, use `AddRange` and do it once. A simple benchmark would help in confirming performance as well.

Comment: Does that fit? `plist.AddRange(richTextBox1.Lines.Where(line => line != "").ToArray());` or `line.Trim() != ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just write that in one line after the condition check:

```
if ( checkBox1.Checked && richTextBox1.Lines.Length > 0 )
  plist.AddRange(richTextBox1.Lines.Where(line => line != "").ToArray()); //or line.Trim() != ""
```

I don't think you'll get any speed optimization except for the unnecessary `ToString`, but the code is now short, clean, more robust and more easily maintainable.